# Turn mixed string into datetime object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date column that has the following format:

```
date
10jan2018
12feb2018
14mar2018
```

And so on. I guess the best approach is to turn the middle string into a number, and then apply `todatetime()` so I created a dictionary like this:

```
dict_month={'jan':01, 'feb':02,'mar':03,'apr':04,'may':05,'jun':06'
      'jul':07, 'aug':08,'sep':09,'oct':10,'nov':11,'dec':12}
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed. Maybe I could use a regex, but I'm not sure how to combine regex and dictionary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a `format` to `pd.to_datetime()`.  `%b` is the month as locale’s abbreviated name (and is case-insensitive in this direction):

```
>>> df
        date
0  10jan2018
1  12feb2018
2  14mar2018

>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
0   2018-01-10
1   2018-02-12
2   2018-03-14
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

From `datetime` module: [Formatting directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).